# How to display content of one page to another page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie in rails. I have created a demo project with a controller products_controller.rb and when i type this url `http://localhost:3000/products` i can see the list of existing products from the database. But I need to create a new page named "display" and url should be `http://localhost:3000/products/display` where my products should display. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for Rails' [RESTful routing structure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

Every time you use `resources :controller` in your `routes` file, it creates [7 routes for that controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions):

> - Index
> - New
> - Create
> - Edit
> - Update
> - Show
> - Destroy

To me, it seems you're trying to use the `show` method:

---

**Show**

Rails' `show` method basically shows a particular object on the page, like this:

```
/products/234
```

This displays the product on its own

The way you code this is very simple:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

You can then link to this with this [URL helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers):

```
<%= link_to "View", products_path(product.id) %>
```

This will allow you to show the products you click onto

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a secondary action and not just a different path to the index action, you need a custom action on the collection:

in your routes.rb

```
resources :products do
  collection do
    get :display
  end
end
```

Then in your products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController
  def display
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

and then create a display.html.erb/haml/... in your app/views/products folder and fill it out with whatever you want :-)

If you just want a different path to the index action, you could add a custom path. The routing guide explains this better then i could, so i just link to it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just want to have a customized url for the index page of products.

You can achieve that in the following way-

in your routes.rb

```
get "/products/display" => "products#index"
resources :products
```

Just remember to put resources below your custom route entry.

I Hope this helps you!!