# Rails: custom url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie in rails. In my demo app I can show all my products list in  `http://localhost:3000/products` and each product has show, edit, delete option. When I click on the show link, I go to the specific product and I get a url for that product like 
 `http://localhost:3000/products/5` (that is id after /products/) but I want two things to add

1) When I click on show button my url should be something like this

```
http://localhost:3000/products/display
```

Id should not be after products. Only display should be.

2)and I want to add another button from where I can show all the products list in another url like  `http://localhost:3000/products/displayall`  that is my all products will show both in  `http://localhost:3000/products` and  `http://localhost:3000/products/displayall`

Comment: Looks like you've double-posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678627/how-to-display-content-of-one-page-to-another-page-in-rails). Did you have any luck with those solutions, or the ones posted below in response to _this_ question?

Comment: and what is the functionality behind `/products/display`

Comment: Any luck with this so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this to overwrite the default CRuD behavior

```
resource :products do
  get ':id/show', :to => :show
  get ':id/display', :to => :show
  get 'displayall', :to => :index, :on => :collection
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

As in the link below described under 2.10.1 use :on => :member to add a restful link who is able to recognize `/products/:id/display` otherwise the example below.

Comment: If you run `rake routes`, you'll see that this does not create the collection routes that the OP has cited in the question.

Comment: @zeantsoi typo. i've changed

Comment: Have you actually looked at the routes? The routes you have specified _do not_ include the route cited in the first addition.

Answer (score 0):

You've cited the show, edit, and delete actions, so you're presumably defining resourceful routes. If this is correct, you will be able to add custom routes to your `Product` routes [via a `collection` block](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions):

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :products do
  collection do
    get 'display'
    get 'displayall'
  end
end
```

This adds the following two set of named routes:

```
         display_products GET    /products/display(.:format)                              products#display
      displayall_products GET    /products/displayall(.:format)                           products#displayall
```

These routes point to the `products#display` and `products#displayall` controller actions, respectively.